# How do write a toggleable hold down key in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to write an AHK script that allows me to do the following:

Press the <kbd>t</kbd> key to toggle the <kbd>1</kbd> key being held down so that it types a bunch of 1's indefinitely until I press the <kbd>t</kbd> key again.

Just to be clear: I want it to repeatedly send the 1 key input and not send the command to hold the 1 key down without typing anything.

I'm aware that this could be done with a loop but unsure of how to do it; Although the <kbd>t</kbd> key should start and stop the loop.
I also don't want the loop to be affected (even if I pressed other keys) unless it is by me manually stopping it using the t key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you want the key <kbd>t</kbd> to start and stop the
repeating of the key <kbd>1</kbd>, acting as a switch.

Below is a script that does this, repeating the key at intervals of 200 milliseconds:

```
#Persistent
repeating1 = 0

t::
if (repeating1 = 0)
{
    repeating1 = 1
    SetTimer, repeat1, 200
}
else
{
    repeating1 = 0
    SetTimer, repeat1, Off
}
return

repeat1:
send, 1
return
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
toggle := False

z UP::
toggle := !toggle

Loop {
    If (!toggle) {
    send,{z UP}
        break
    }
    send,{z DOWN}
sleep 10
}
Return
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please consider making your answer even better by explaining the key points about how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggle = 1
    
t::
toggle := !toggle
If (toggle) 
    send,{1 Up}
else
    send,{1 Down}
return
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?